# Android/java - best practice for breaking up one large class full of calculations

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, refactoring

I am working on a simple sleep-aid app that allows users to choose a starting number of breaths per minute, a goal number of breaths per minute, and a total duration. The app then flashes a dim light on and off to match their chosen breaths per minute, slowing down over 5 mins to their goal, and then keeps going until the chosen duration.

In order to do this I just wrote a whole bunch of calculations in the OnCreate method of a class extending android.app.Activity, but coming back months later I am now concerned about the readability/best practice so am now thinking I should either break it down into either multiple functions/classes, or create a utils class comprised of easily testable functions that each do part of the calculation.

Here is the onCreate:

```
public class LightPulse extends Activity {
public LightPulse(){

}

//Hides the status bar to allow true black background
public void hideStatusBar() {
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        getWindow().getDecorView()
                .setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
                );
    }
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.light_pulse);

    //prevent the screen from automatically locking before the light pulse duration is over
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);


    hideStatusBar();

    //Enable stop button
    Button stopButton = findViewById(R.id.stop_button);
    stopButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            finish();
        }
    });

    //Get data passed to LightPulse activity from home UI
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    //Set background to selected colour
    final ImageView lightPulseImage = findViewById(R.id.image_pulsing_light);
    lightPulseImage.setBackgroundColor(intent.getIntExtra("colour", 0));


    //Get total duration, start breath duration, and goal breath duration in milliseconds.
    int duration = Integer.valueOf(intent.getStringExtra("duration").substring(0,2))*60000;
    Integer startBreathDuration = 60000/intent.getIntExtra("startBPM", 0);
    Integer goalBreathDuration = 60000/intent.getIntExtra("goalBPM", 0);

    //Calculate difference in milliseconds between start and goal duration.
    Integer BreathDelta = goalBreathDuration - startBreathDuration;
    //Calculate the average breath length when moving from start to goal. This is just the midpoint.
    int averageBreathDuration = (startBreathDuration + goalBreathDuration)/2;

    Log.i("debug", "onCreate: Start Breath duration: " + startBreathDuration + " Goal Breath duration: " + goalBreathDuration + " Breath Delta: " + BreathDelta + " Average Breath DUration: " + averageBreathDuration + " total duration: " + duration);

    //Transition period is 5 mins, need to calculate the number of breaths in 5 mins if all breaths were at average
    Integer breathsInFiveMinutesAverage = 300000/averageBreathDuration;

    Log.i("debug", "onCreate: Average breaths in 5 minutes: " + breathsInFiveMinutesAverage);

    //Calculate how much to decrease breath duration by each time, in order to be consistent and move to goal breath duration in 5 mins
    Integer breathDurationShift = BreathDelta/breathsInFiveMinutesAverage;

    Log.i("debug", "onCreate: Breath duration shift: " + breathDurationShift);

    //Instantiate animatorSet for playing sequential animators
    AnimatorSet pulseSet = new AnimatorSet();
    //Instantiate animator list to store pulsing light animators
    List<Animator> animations = new ArrayList<>();

    //Integer for tracking how long the transition set of animators takes in milliseconds
    Integer totalTimeForFirstAnimations = 0;

    //Mutable breath duration integer for transition from start to goal BPM in for loop
    int breathDuration = startBreathDuration;

    //For loop to create the initial set of animators for the transition between start and goal BPM, over 5 minutes
    for(int i = 0; i<breathsInFiveMinutesAverage; i++){
        Log.i("debug", "onCreate: " + breathDuration);
        Log.i("debug", "onCreate colour is: " + intent.getIntExtra("colour", 0));
        //Create the animators to fade in and out one time and add them to the list. Exhale/inhale duration is split 60/40
        final ObjectAnimator fadeInAnimator = ObjectAnimator
                .ofFloat(lightPulseImage, View.ALPHA, 0f, 1f)
                .setDuration(Math.round(breathDuration*0.8));
        animations.add(fadeInAnimator);
        final ObjectAnimator fadeOutAnimator = ObjectAnimator
                .ofFloat(lightPulseImage, View.ALPHA, 1f, 0f)
                .setDuration(Math.round(breathDuration*1.2));
        animations.add(fadeOutAnimator);
        //update the duration for the next animation by adding on the previously calculated shift
        breathDuration = breathDuration + breathDurationShift;
        //update total time for transition animations
        totalTimeForFirstAnimations = totalTimeForFirstAnimations + breathDuration;
    }
    Log.i("debug", "onCreate: Total time for first set of animations: " + totalTimeForFirstAnimations);
    //Calculate remaining time after transition is done, for debugging
    int remainingDuration = duration-totalTimeForFirstAnimations;
    //Calculate how many breaths can be done in the remaining time at the goal breath duration
    int numberOfRepeatsRemaining = remainingDuration/goalBreathDuration;

    Log.i("debug", "onCreate: remaining duration: " + remainingDuration + " Number of repeats: " + numberOfRepeatsRemaining);
    Log.i("debug", "onCreate: Goal breath duration: " + goalBreathDuration);


    long totalTimeOfRemainingAnimations = 0;

    //Create breathe in and out animators which repeat for the remaining number of breaths, with 5 extra of each added to allow the screen to automatically lock before the process is finished
    for(int i = 0; i<(numberOfRepeatsRemaining)+5; i++){
        final ObjectAnimator fadeInAnimator = ObjectAnimator
                .ofFloat(lightPulseImage, View.ALPHA, 0f, 1f)
                .setDuration(Math.round(goalBreathDuration*0.8));
        animations.add(fadeInAnimator);
        final ObjectAnimator fadeOutAnimator = ObjectAnimator
                .ofFloat(lightPulseImage, View.ALPHA, 1f, 0f)
                .setDuration(Math.round(goalBreathDuration*1.2));
        animations.add(fadeOutAnimator);
        totalTimeOfRemainingAnimations = totalTimeOfRemainingAnimations + Math.round(goalBreathDuration*0.8) + Math.round(goalBreathDuration*1.2);
    }
    Log.i("debug", "onCreate: total time of final animations " + totalTimeOfRemainingAnimations);


    Log.i("debug", "onCreate: animations list size: " + animations.size());

    //Calculate the total time of animations in milliseconds, for debugging
    int totalAnimationTime = totalTimeForFirstAnimations + (numberOfRepeatsRemaining*goalBreathDuration);

    Log.i("debug", "onCreate: animations total time in milliseconds: " + totalAnimationTime);

    //After the chosen duration is over, allow the screen to lock.
    final Handler screenOffHandler = new Handler();
    screenOffHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Log.i("debug", "times up");
            getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

            //End the activity once the screen has  been given time to lock
            final Handler screenOffHandler = new Handler();
            screenOffHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Log.i("debug", "Exiting light pulse activity");
                    finish();
                }
            }, 30000);
        }
    }, duration);

    //Add the animator list to the animatorSet, and play them sequentially
    pulseSet.playSequentially(animations);
    pulseSet.start();




}
```

}

And in the HomeFragment class here is where that activity is called:

```
//set up start button
    final Button startButton = root.findViewById(R.id.start_button);
    startButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        //when pressed, LightPulse activity is started, and is provided with the selected values for duration, start BPM, goal BPM, and light colour
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), LightPulse.class);
            intent.putExtra("startBPM", homeViewModel.getStartingBPM().getValue());
            intent.putExtra("goalBPM", homeViewModel.getGoalBPM().getValue());
            intent.putExtra("colour", homeViewModel.getColour().getValue());
            intent.putExtra("duration", spinner.getSelectedItem().toString());
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

Is there a recommended way to break this up? I would like to write a unit test suite for this, but a lot of the calculations re-use the same variables which adds a lot of complexity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend using a MVVM architecture pattern.  You are doing a bunch of calculations on the main thread.  This is kotlin.  Something like:

```
class LightPulseViewModel: ViewModel() {

    fun calculateBreathsDuration(duration: Int, startBreathsPerMinute: Int, goalBreathsPerMinute: Int): Int {
      var value = 0
      //do your work
      return value
    }

    fun calculateAnimationTime(): Long {
      var value = 0L
      //do your work
      return value
    }


}
```

Then in LightPulse:

```
public class LightPulse extends Activity {
public LightPulse(){

}

LightPulseViewModel viewModel;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.light_pulse);
    viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(LightPulseViewModel::class.java);

    ///whereever you need to do calculations
    Integer breathsduration = viewModel.calculateBreathsDuration(Integer.valueOf(intent.getStringExtra("duration").substring(0,2))*60000, 60000/intent.getIntExtra("startBPM", 0), 60000/intent.getIntExtra("goalBPM", 0))

    //do the same for animation duration calculations here.  

 }
}
```

for more info on MVVM patterns:  https://www.journaldev.com/20292/android-mvvm-design-pattern

Comment: Thank you for the link! The HomeFragment class which starts the Activity already uses a HomeViewModel class, so hopefully I can use that as a basis (along with the article you linked) in the refactor.